# How to create Angular Cli 4 dynamic table by *ngFor.?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I am working in automation project using `Angular CLI`. How to create the dynamic columns and dynamic row table using the `*ngFor.`?

In previous version of angular like AngularJS. I had done this method with the help of [AngularJS dynamic table with unknown number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851484/angularjs-dynamic-table-with-unknown-number-of-columns)

How to solve this?

Comment: So, you're asking how to use ngFor? Why don't you read the angular documentation?

Comment: I think the problem is a pretty fundamental one when it comes to dynamically repeating elements. There are countless examples and documentation sources out there as mentioned by @JBNizet

Comment: I am not asking how to use *ngFor , I am asking that how to create a dynamic table with *ngFor. That is Creating a Table with unknown column in JSON @JB

Comment: The exact same way it's done in the answer you linked to, except you would use ngFor instead of ng-repeat.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried it on the same way but it not worked in the Angular 4 cli.

Comment: Then your question should be: *Here's the code of the component: <code>. Here is the code of the template: <code>. I expect this to be displayed: <expected output> but instead I have this <output/error>*. It should not be *how to create the dynamic columns and dynamic row table using the ngFor*

Comment: @JBNizet ok dude. I am sorry about the question format. This was my first question in stack overflow so that's why.? If u can solve this problem pls help me.

Comment: How about you editing your question to make it look like I suggested, first?

Comment: @JBNizet look I am not here to editing or present a question like beautiful. I need to solve my issue so that's what I am asking here. If you can means you answer other wise keep quit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let me conclude this discussion. I have solved my problem by doing this in my controller. Here is my code: `StudentsDetails = [];

```
columns: string[] = [];

  constructor(private newService: StudentsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newService.fetchData()
    .subscribe(responseStudentsDetails => {
      this.StudentsDetails = responseStudentsDetails;
      this.columns = Object.keys(this.StudentsDetails[0]);
    })
  };
```

`Since StudentsDetails is my JSON array. I extract the keys from the StudentsDetails[0]. Then, I added the previous Wesley's code in my html file.`

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let column of columns | filter : filter">{{column}}
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let row of StudentsDetails | filter : filter | paginate: { itemsPerPage: items, currentPage: Page }">
                <td *ngFor="let column of columns | filter : filter">
                  {{row[column]}}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="page" [(ngModel)]="items">
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>25</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Page" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="page-no" placeholder="Page">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <nav>
                <ul class="pagination">
                  <li class="page-item">
                    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="Page = $event"></pagination-controls>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--/.row-->
```

` Hence my issue is Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have nested `ngFor` statements, you would also need to set up your data object to make sure it's easy to work with, but this is how you would achieve this

```
<table *ngIf="columns">
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{column.header}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let column of columns">
            <td *ngFor="let row of column.rows">
                {{row.whatever}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what I want to do in the {{ expression }}. like {{ columns }} like that.

Comment: I updated my answer, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Dude actually I tried your code but it doesn't work for me. will u please post your code in Codepen or  something like that and share the link to me.