# Angular 2 ngFor table creating

Tags: angular

How to create table with angular 2 with **non fixed number of columns** or by using a loop to create number of columns based on number of this loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS dynamic table with unknown number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851484/angularjs-dynamic-table-with-unknown-number-of-columns)

Comment: Looks like it's not a dublicate, this question is about Angular 2, not Angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use *ngFor loops on template.

```
 <table *ngIf="data">
    <tr *ngFor="let title of data.titles">
      <th> {{ title }} </th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let value of data.values">
      <td> {{ value }} </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

this is a small example you have to fit it on you data structure

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic html you need for that:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let column of tableColumns">Content</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

`*ngFor` works based on array length, so in component you can just create an empty array and specify it's length, like this:

```
this.tableColumns = new Array(5);
```

Here is the working plunker with 5 columns: https://plnkr.co/edit/Cx8CssdO3V63dzQH7HSL?p=preview

Comment: If there are multiple rows, is there a way to avoid using the *ngFor multiple times on each row?