# How to auto-detect headers of json for a table in Angular4?

Tags: json, angular, html-table

first of all sorry for my bad english. I'm creating a component named "table" on my application.
This component receives a JSON delievered by Laravel Backend. I'm trying to make a dinamic component for all jsons that it can receive.
I mean, this component will be able to draw a table with the fields that the json contains.
I want that if i receive a json that have "name, age, adress", or "name, country, state", the table shows it exactly.

Is there any already existing component that provides me this? Because all components that i found the columns must be configured previously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could definitely create a simple component to do this.  Here's a plunk that shows one way you could get started.

https://plnkr.co/edit/jZKJl9yDnXCvGCnxqlHM

The component is `my-table` and you pass in your array of objects.  This particular implementation expects each element of the array to have the same keys.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-table',
  template: `
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let header of headers">
          {{ header }}
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
        <td *ngFor="let cell of objectKeys(row)">
          {{ row[cell] }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  `,
})
export class MyTableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() data: any[];
  headers: any;
  private objectKeys: any;

  constructor() {
    this.objectKeys = Object.keys;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.headers = Object.keys(this.data[0]);
  }
}
```

And you'd set up the data:

```
this.mydata = [
  { one: "hello", two: "world", three: "foo", four: 1 },
  { one: "xxx", two: "aaa", three: "foo", four: 1 },
  { one: "yyy", two: "bbb", three: "foo", four: 1 }  
]
```

And use the component like so:

```
<my-table [data]="mydata"></my-table>
```

Comment: Perfect! This helped me out. Im now trying to make a pipe for filter all columns.. do you have some idea?

Answer (score 1):

See [AngularJS dynamic table with unknown number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851484/angularjs-dynamic-table-with-unknown-number-of-columns).

Also, pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: His question was about Angular 4, which is not all that relevant to AngularJS.  But I do agree with your "also..." paragraph.

Comment: Yea, i was kind of just going off of a quick google search for something similar without much to go on from the question. Glad you were able to provide a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys(row)` to get array of keys of that row. I guess you have JSON with array of rows, right? In that case, you can simply do this on the first `row` and then build the table dynamically.

```
const data = [
    { field1: 'value 1', field2: 123, field3: 'adsaosd' },
    { field1: 'value 2', field2: 123, field3: 'adsaosd' },
    { field1: 'value 3', field2: 123, field3: 'adsaosd' },
    { field1: 'value 4', field2: 123, field3: 'adsaosd' },
]

const keys = Object.keys(data[0]); // TODO check whether there is at least one row
```